# Where is the data such as block dimension stored in the memory.(CUDA programming)?

Tags: cuda

this is related to parallel programming. the data used such as block dimension and grid dimensions during kernel launch.
my question is that where are these stored in memory?

Answer (score 4):

They are not stored in memory in any conventional sense. The PTX virtual machine defines a number of [special registers](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#special-registers) which are used to make grid and block dimensions along with the corresponding indices available in device code.